# Addition title to plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

How can I add titles to each subplot here?

```
 fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=2, figsize=(16,8))
 for city, nrow in zip(['City1', 'City1'], [0, 1]):
    df = data[(data.city==city)&(data.sdate.dt.year==2021)]
    for col, ncol in zip(['parameterX', 'parameterY', 'parameterZ', 'parameterH'], [0,1, 2,3]):
    axs[nrow, ncol].hist(df[col], bins=50)
```

[image]

Comment: `axs[nrow, ncol].set_title("Title")` within the loop

Answer (score 2):

just do at the end

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=2, figsize=(16,8))
 for city, nrow in zip(['City1', 'City1'], [0, 1]):
    df = data[(data.city==city)&(data.sdate.dt.year==2021)]
    for col, ncol in zip(['parameterX', 'parameterY', 'parameterZ', 'parameterH'], [0,1, 2,3]):
        axs[nrow, ncol].hist(df[col], bins=50)
        axs[nrow, ncol].set_title('my_subplot_title')
```

Answer (score 1):

Customize the title with column, row name and add it as below.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=2, figsize=(16,8))
for city, nrow in zip(['City1', 'City1'], [0, 1]):
    df = data[(data.city==city)&(data.sdate.dt.year==2021)]
    for col, ncol in zip(['parameterX', 'parameterY', 'parameterZ', 'parameterH'], [0,1, 2,3]):
        axs[nrow, ncol].hist(df[col], bins=50)
        title=city+'_'+col
        axs[nrow, ncol].set_title(title)
```